# Translate two strings in different languages at the same time using @ngx-translate/core?

Tags: angular, typescript, translate, angular11, ngx-translate

I am working on an Angular@11 application and facing an issue.
In my app there are two panels, left and right. I want to translate the left panel in Spanish and the right one in German.

Using @ngx-translate/core, it will translate both panels in any one language at a time, but I want to translate both panels in different languages.

Any kind of help is appreciable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by creating your own `translate` pipe, to use it instead of the default one provided by `ngx-translte`.

The new custom `translate` pipe should depend on the same translations provided by `TranslateService`, and handle the most logic handled by the default `translate` pipe, but without handling the `onLangChange`, `onDefaultLangChange`, or `onTranslationChange` events.

You can try something like the following:

```js
import {
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Injectable,
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform,
} from '@angular/core';
import { isObservable } from 'rxjs';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Injectable()
@Pipe({
  name: 'translateBy',
  pure: false, // required to update the value when the promise is resolved
})
export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  value: string = '';
  lastKey: string;
  lastParams: any[];

  constructor(
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private _ref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  updateValue(
    key: string,
    interpolateParams?: Object,
    translations?: any
  ): void {
    let onTranslation = (res: string) => {
      this.value = res !== undefined ? res : key;
      this.lastKey = key;
      this._ref.markForCheck();
    };
    if (translations) {
      let res = this.translate.getParsedResult(
        translations,
        key,
        interpolateParams
      );
      if (isObservable(res.subscribe)) {
        res.subscribe(onTranslation);
      } else {
        onTranslation(res);
      }
    } else this.translate.get(key, interpolateParams).subscribe(onTranslation);
  }

  transform(query: string, lang: string, ...args: any[]): any {
    if (!query || !query.length) {
      return query;
    }

    // if we ask another time for the same key, return the last value
    if (equals(query, this.lastKey) && equals(args, this.lastParams)) {
      return this.value;
    }

    let interpolateParams: Object;
    if (!!args[0] && args.length) {
      if (typeof args[0] === 'string' && args[0].length) {
        // we accept objects written in the template such as {n:1}, {'n':1}, {n:'v'}
        // which is why we might need to change it to real JSON objects such as {"n":1} or {"n":"v"}
        let validArgs: string = args[0]
          .replace(/(\')?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(\')?(\s)?:/g, '"$2":')
          .replace(/:(\s)?(\')(.*?)(\')/g, ':"$3"');
        try {
          interpolateParams = JSON.parse(validArgs);
        } catch (e) {
          throw new SyntaxError(
            `Wrong parameter in TranslatePipe. Expected a valid Object, received: ${args[0]}`
          );
        }
      } else if (typeof args[0] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(args[0])) {
        interpolateParams = args[0];
      }
    }

    // store the query, in case it changes
    this.lastKey = query;

    // store the params, in case they change
    this.lastParams = args;

    // set the value
    this.updateValue(
      query,
      interpolateParams,
      this.translate.translations[lang] // <<<<< This is the main requried change to return the translation for the provided lang.
    );

    return this.value;
  }
}
```

And in the component, you can use it like the following:

```html
<span>ES Value: {{ "MAIN_TITLE" | translateBy: "es" }}</span>
<span>DE Value: {{ "MAIN_TITLE" | translateBy: "de" }}</span>
```

**P.S.** The above custom pipe (and the original pipe also) uses the `equals` function to check if the `args` and `lastParams` are equal or not. You can copy the `ngx-translate` [eqauls](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/efcb4f43a645d9ac630aae8e50b60cc883e675fd/projects/ngx-translate/core/src/lib/util.ts#L15) function and use it in your code, or you can use any other deeply `equals` functions (e.g. `lodash` [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual))